# what does --- and ---- mean in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, comments

I know `--` means starting of comment in mysql. But what does `---` and `----` mean?? See my console log.

```
mysql> --
mysql> ---
    -> 
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-' at line 1
mysql> ----
    -> 
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

- First one seems a comment.
- Second one is NOT
- Third one is not too. They are expecting something.

I wrote an sql file that contains header comments started with `---` characters. Due to this next query does not run. It throws error. Like this.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-' at line 1

Comment: Where did you see them used?

Comment: @JanDvorak: "I wrote an sql file that contains header comments started with `---` characters."

Comment: I used them. I didn't saw them used anywhere. I thought its just like C's `//`. Adding more `/` wont matter.

Comment: Strange! But what version of MySQL are you using. Mine is `server version: 5.0.22-community-nt` and it accepted all `--`, `---`, `----`, and `-----` followed by no space but a return key returned no errors but `mysql>` prompt. !!

Comment: @Ravinder `MySQL Server version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There needs to be whitespace or a control character after the second dash. From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html):

> MySQL Server supports three comment styles:
>
> - From a `#` character to the end of the line.
> - From a `--` sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the `--` (double-dash) comment style **requires the second dash to be followed by
>     at least one whitespace or control character** (such as a space, tab,
>     newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL
>     comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.8.5.5, “`--` as the Start of
>     a Comment”.
> - From a `/*` sequence to the following `*/` sequence, as in the C programming language. This syntax enables a comment to extend over
>     multiple lines because the beginning and closing sequences need not be
>     on the same line.

(Emphasis mine.) And, as usual, this only applies to MySQL. :P

Comment: Then what it _is_, if not a comment?

Comment: @JanDvorak: A syntax error. What is `-*`, if not a negative multiplication? :)

Comment: I thought OP saw this used in foreign code. I was mistaken, apparently.

Comment: Thanks @minitech. I always added a space after `--` to make the comment readable. Never thought its required!

Comment: Why would they support both `#` _and_ `--` if the latter is so annoying to handle?

Comment: @Someone: `--` is the standard SQL form, and “followed by a space” isn’t *that* annoying.

Comment: Then _why support `#`_?

Comment: @Someone: MySQL does that kind of thing a lot. I encourage you not to use `#`.

Answer (score 2):

This nothing but syntax check error,

```
Other than '--', mysql considering everything as sql statement. Since
'---' is not a valid statement it's showing error.
that means there should be at least one space after '--' then only it will be considered as valid comment.
```

Hope this helps you,

Comment: What does that mean? Can you rephrase?